# Memcpy trick to copy reversed array

Tags: c

Below question got in an interview.

How to use memcpy to copy 1 array to other in such a way that target array has reversed data as compared to source.

Still not able to get the logic.

Comment: `memcpy` copies (byte/word) from src to dest by traversing forward through the memory. Doesn't give you a explicit control over direction.

Comment: Nasty question to be sprung in an interview. Trick question maybe?

Comment: Are you sure about the memcpy part? Maybe the question was just: "create a reversed copy of the array", probably using a for loop, which would only test basic programming skill.

Comment: @KarstenKoop. You could use `memcpy` instead of `=` in that loop.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy
I would say that the obvious "trick" is quite explicitly forbidden, seeing that `size_t` does not allow negatives.

So the question is probably a trick question and the answer would be

a)
Not.

or

b)
By using a loop which iterates byte by byte backward through source and forward through destination.

I had a question like that for graduation, asking for a solution, which turns out to be excrutiatingly slow, inefficient and uncool - but possible.
The point is to spot that it is possible, though not what anybody would actually do.

Answer (score 0):

Let's navigate through the source code of opensource and see the basic memcpy code:

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/memcpy.c

```
/* Public domain.  */
#include <stddef.h>

void *
memcpy (void *dest, const void *src, size_t len)
{
  char *d = dest;
  const char *s = src;
  while (len--)
    *d++ = *s++;
  return dest;
}
```

Do you see the `*d++ = *s++;` part? That means you simply **can't** move backwards, only fordward, with the `++` operator.

So, how do I memcpy + reverse? Well, you need an additional `memreverse` function to do the last part or create a function, `revmemcpy`

```
#include <stddef.h>

void *
revmemcpy (void *dest, const void *src, size_t len)
{
  char *d = dest + len - 1;
  const char *s = src;
  while (len--)
    *d-- = *s++;
  return dest;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `len-1`?

Comment: Wouldn't matter as the update statement is after the assignment. But it's good now.

Comment: The question was not "Use something closely related to `memcpy` to do XY". It was "How to use `memcpy` to do XY". Your answer misses the point.

Comment: `in such a way that target array has reversed data` can be misinterpreted.
You understand `to do`.
I understand `use anything closely related`

Comment: It could be ok in an interview say "no", but most of HR people are unnecessarily optimistic. Doing an incorrect solution, but correct approach, can be better than say simply **no**.

Of course, you can memcpy and memswap the half of the buffer and it is certainly a correct approach.